# How to make a label inside a PlotWidget?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm making a GUI using Qt and pyqtgraph. It's got several PlotWidgets in it - here's a section of it:

[image: GUI with a plot]

I'd like to include the mouse cursor position (in scaled units) as a label within the plot, a bit like the pyqtgraph crosshair example:

[image: pygraph crosshair example]

The example works by adding a `LabelItem` to a `GraphicsWindow` like this:

```
win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
label = pg.LabelItem(justify='right')
p1 = win.addPlot(row=1, col=0)
```

But I don't have a `GraphicsWindow`, just a normal Qt window (built using the Designer) with PlotWidgets in it. I can't seem to add a `LabelItem` or a `TextItem` to a `PlotWidget`. I'm sure there must be a 'standard' way of doing this, but I can't figure it out and Google doesn't seem to know. Any ideas?

**Edit**: here's a snippet of my code from the window's `__init__` function:

```
self.B_field_plot.setLabels(title='Magnetic field', left='B [T]', bottom='z [m]')
self.label = pg.LabelItem(justify="right")
self.B_field_plot.addItem(self.label)
self.label.setText('Hello')
```

The label does not appear.

Comment: Could you show me your code please

Comment: Where is your plotWidget?

Comment: B_field_plot is plotWidget?

Comment: It's the `B_field_plot`

Answer (score -1):

Although it is a bit late now to answer this question, but I will put my answer in case someone else needed it.

You have to change the source file generated by the QTdesigner. 
find the line that creates the plotwidget and embedded the title in it. 
`self.plot = PlotWidget(title= "something")`